# Query filtering in Django with sqlite

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite

I've tried the following query with Django,

```
def search(search_text):
    q  = Info.objects.filter(title__contains=str(search_text))
    print q.query
```

The query that get printed is

```
SELECT "d"."id", "d"."foo" FROM "d_info" WHERE "d_info"."title" LIKE %hello% ESCAPE '\'
```

The query fails because the text after LIKE doesn't have quotes around it. The query succeeds when I run the query on the sql prompt with quotes around the text after LIKE like below

```
SELECT "d"."id", "d"."foo" FROM "d_info" WHERE "d_info"."title" LIKE '%hello%' ESCAPE '\'
```

How do I get Django to add the quotes around the search_text so that the query succeeds ?

I'm using Djanog with sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment above as the answer

It so turns out the query works within Django, but when asked to print the query and if I copy the query printed and execute it in a mysql shell or sqlite shell, it doesn't work. 
Django is probably printing the query wrong

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out with Postgresql 8.3. The query is generated without quotes. However executing the filter returns a valid queryset with expected instances. Can you try executing

```
q = Info.objects.filter(title__contains=str(search_text))
print q.count()
```

and see if it works?

Comment: It isn't different from what I have. Did you mean something else ?

Comment: I meant to ask, did you execute the query behind the (lazy) queryset? `Print q.count()` will tell you if the query fired OK.

Comment: Sorry I missed the 2nd statement, it so turns out the query works within Django, but when asked to print the query and if I execute the same query in a mysql shell or sqlite shell, it doesn't work. Django is probably printing the query wrong.